# Need to modify WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: woocommerce, elementor

I need to modify WooCommerce product page product image and galery (https://mythos-archives.com/product/salvator/) like on https://professor-e.com/collections/all-products/products/forgotten-materials-pleats-bomber. It is product galery carousel with thumbnail below it, right justified.

I use Elementor custom product page template to replace existing product thumbnail section with Elementor image carousel widget, but I don't know how to add thumbnail below it. Anyone can help me to modify it? I use elementor, don't have programming skill, only using snippet code plugin to modify anything.